# Difference between Enum.each and list comprehension.

Tags: elixir

In Elixir, we can print the value of a list one by one by using Enum.each function.

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
Enum.each(a, fn(x) -> IO.puts x end)
```

the output is:

```
1
2
3
:ok
```

Using list comprehension to do the same task:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
for x <- a, do: IO.puts x
```

the outputs is:

```
1
2
3
[:ok, :ok, :ok]
```

At the end of the output, Enum.each function returns one :ok, list comprehension returns three :ok. What is the difference between the two approach?
Sorry for this dumb question. I read the official elixir doc. but didn't find the answer.

Comment: This is not a dumb question! This is an excellent question, as it showcases fundamentals of the language.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The answers provided so far, although correct do not really address the core of your problem. The core of your problem here is that you are unfamiliar with how `Enum.each`, `Enum.map`, `for x <- a` etc. are implemented under the hood.

`Enum.map` under the hood is nothing but a recursive function that accepts two inputs:

1. a list
2. a function that needs to be applied to each element in that list

The return value of this recursive function is a new list.

To clarify even more:
say you have as input the list `[1, 2, 3, 4]` and a function: `fn e -> e * 2 end` then you will get the new list `[2, 4, 6, 8]`

`Enum.map` could simply be implemented like this:

```
defmodule MyEnum do
  def map(list, fun) do 
    if Enum.empty?(list) do
      []                                # Null case reached, stop recursing.
    else
      [head | tail] = list              # obtain the first element in the list, assign that value to `head`. Store the remaining list inside the variable `tail`
      projected_value = fun.(head)        # This is where your function gets applied
      [ projected_value | map(tail, fun)] # Recurse
    end
  end
end
```

So `MyEnum.map([1,2,3], fn e -> e * 2 end)` will return to you the list: `[2, 4, 6]`

Now suppose that you utilize the function `IO.puts/2` here, like:
`MyEnum.map([1,2,3], fn e -> IO.puts(e) end)`, the variable `projected_value` will eventually be the return value of `IO.puts/2`. It prints the value to the screen, and it returns an `:ok` atom.

This means that the list you are building up in this case would be accumulating the atoms `:ok` over each new recursion.

The comprehension `for x <- a` under the hood is something similar to Enum.map, a recursive function that will apply a provided function to each element of your list, but just with a different syntax.

`Enum.each` is also a recursive function under the hood, but it will just loop over every element, not caring about accumulating anything in the process. This is how you could implement it:

```
defmodule MyEnum do
  def each(list, fun) do 
    if Enum.empty?(list) do
      :ok                          # Return `:ok` to communicate the entire list has been traversed
    else
      [head | tail] = list
      fun.(head)                   # Only apply the function to the element of the list, and do not care about its return value
      each(tail, fun)              # Continue to traverse the list recursively
    end
  end
end
```

As you can see, this function will always return `:ok` and `Enum.map` will always return a new list.

All of this is elementary stuff, so:

1. If your understand what is happening under the hood and;
2. you understand that in essence `Enum.map` and `for x <- [1,2,3]` are basically one and the same recursive function with just a different interface

`|>` then all your questions should be clarified.

In addition, the same constructs are provided in `Javascript` as well. If you do `[1,2,3,4].map` or `[1,2,3,4].each` in JS, they do the exact same thing as in `Elixir`, so you could find more clarity in understanding these constructs in `Javascript` first if you still have a problem understanding the differences.

Comment: @KevinJohnson Javascript: ` var a = 10; arr=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]; for(i=0;i<5;++i){ a = arr[i] + a} the result is: a = 25 ` In Elixir, ` a = 10; Enum.each(0..4, fn(x) -> a = arr[i] + a) ` This code get an error. ` for I<-0..4, do: a = Enum.at(arr, i) + a` This returns a list not a single value. How can I get the same result as in javascript? thank you !

Comment: You would require a `Enum.reduce` to achieve what you want. Look at the function in Javascript and play with it.

Answer (score 3):

[Enum.each/2](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#each/2) would be good fit, if you want to do something over the collection and you don't care about the result. `:ok` is always return as a result of this function.

List comprehension returns you new collection, which is the result of computation of function call for each element of the original enumable thing (in your case list). Think about it as alternative for `Enum.map/2`.

In your case result is `[:ok, :ok, :ok]`, because `:ok` is also the result for each `IO.puts` call.

Comment: I want to execute a large block of code. May be Enum.each is not a good approach. I tried list comprehension, but didn't get the same result compared with javascript.

Comment: What do you mean by "not the same result"? The resulting data didn't match or was it slower?

Comment: @fr3dch3n I've learned from the elixir forum using list comprehension as for loop. I know elixir is a functional programming language. it doesn't provide any loop. I use for x <- 0..10, do some code here. but didn't get the same result compared with javascript. for(i=0;i<11;++i){some code here} in elixir, I get a list. in javascript, I get a value.(link: https://elixirforum.com/t/how-to-do-a-for-loop-in-elixir-using-only-recursion/595)

Answer (score 1):

Simply put, [`Enum.each/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#each/2) is *an iteration*, while [`Enum.map/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#map/2) *and* the comprehension are both *mappers*, and the comprehension could be *a reducer* at some extent.